# Fastest way to print this in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a text file containing this, where the number on the left says how many of the characters of the right should be there:

```
2 a
1 *
3 $
```

How would I get this output in the fastest time?

```
aa*$$$
```

This is my code, but has N^2 complexity:

```
f = open('a.txt')
for item in f:
    item2=item.split()
    num = int(item2[0])
    for i in range(num):
        line+=item2[1]
print(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: You could put all the bits in a list and use `join` at the end to join them up.

Comment: You could use `item2[1] * int(item[0])`

Comment: And no need to `join` them, just print immediately when you have a bit (with end='')

Comment: In fact, your code does not have N^2 complexity. Two loops does not means N^2.

Answer (score 4):

KISS

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        count, char = line.strip().split(' ')
        print char * int(count),
```

Answer (score 3):

Just print immediately:

```
for item in open('a.txt'):
    num, char = item.strip().split()
    print(int(num) * char, end='')

print()  # Newline
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply strings to repeat them in Python:

`"foo" * 3` gives you `foofoofoo`.

```
line = []
with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        n, c = line.rstrip().split(" ")
        line.append(c * int(n))

print("".join(line))
```

You can print directly but the code above lets you get the output you want in a string if you care about that.

Using a list then `join`ing is more efficient than using `+=` on a string because strings are immutable in Python. This means that a new string must be created for each `+=`. Of course printing immediately avoids this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
f = open('a.txt')

print ''.join(int(item.split()[0]) * item.split()[1] for item in f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually O(sum(n_i)) where n_i is the number in the row i. You can't do any better and none of the solutions in the other answers do, even if they might be faster than yours.